# Splitting the content of brackets without separating the brackets ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am currently working on a ruby program to calculate terms. It works perfectly fine except for one thing: brackets. I need to filter the content or at least, to put the content into an array, but I have tried for an hour to come up with a solution. Here is my code:

```
splitted = term.split(/\(+|\)+/)
```

I need an array instead of the brackets, for example:

```
"1-(2+3)" #=>["1", "-", ["2", "+", "3"]]
```

I already tried this:

```
/(\((?<=.*)\))/
```

but it returned:

```
Invalid pattern in look-behind.
```

Can someone help me with this?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention, that my program will split the term, I only need the content of the brackets to be an array.

Comment: I find stringscanner to be better for this sort of task.

Comment: The invalid message appears to be because in most engines (except Dot-Net) lookbehinds can't be of variable length. The other thing is if you are trying to parse `(2+3)` independently, you can't do that unless Ruby supports recursion. And, I don't know if it does. The alternative is to parse it yourself, character by character keeping track of nesting with a stack.

Comment: This would be a proper example of nesting: `(5-(3*2(4+1)-9)+7)*4`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep track of the hierarchy of parentheses with arrays, you won't manage it just with regular expressions. You'll need to parse the string word by word, and keep a stack of expressions.

Pseudocode:

- Expressions = new stack
- Add new array on stack
- while word in string:

  - if word is "(": Add new array on stack
  - Else if word is ")": Remove the last array from the stack and add it to the (next) last array of the stack
  - Else: Add the word to the last array of the stack
- When exiting the loop, there should be only one array in the stack (if not, you have inconsistent opening/closing parentheses).

Note: If your ultimate goal is to evaluate the expression, you could save time and parse the string in Postfix aka [Reverse-Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).
Also consider using [off-the-shelf libraries](https://github.com/avsej/calculus).

Answer (score 0):

A solution depends on the pattern you expect between the parentheses, which you have not specified. (For example, for `"(st12uv)"` you might want `["st", "12", "uv"]`, `["st12", "uv"]`, `["st1", "2uv"]` and so on).  If, as in your example, it is a natural number followed by a `+`, followed by another natural number, you could do this:

```
str = "1-( 2+ 3)"

r = /
    \(\s*  # match a left parenthesis followed by >= 0 whitespace chars
    (\d+)  # match one or more digits in a capture group
    \s*    # match >= 0 whitespace chars 
    (\+)   # match a plus sign in a capture group
    \s*    # match >= 0 whitespace chars 
    (\d+)  # match one or more digits in a capture group
    \s*    # match >= 0 whitespace chars 
    \)       # match a right parenthesis
    /x

str.scan(r0).first
  => ["2", "+", "3"]
```

Suppose instead `+` could be `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`. Then you could change:

```
(\+)
```

to:

```
([-+*\/])
```

Note that, in a character class, `+` needn't be escaped and `-` needn't be escaped if it is the first or last character of the class (as in those cases it would not signify a range).

Incidentally, you received the error message, "Invalid pattern in look-behind" because Ruby's lookarounds cannot contain variable-length matches (i.e., `.*`). With positive lookbehinds you can get around that by using `\K` instead. For example,

```
r = /
    \d+ # match one or more digits
    \K  # forget everything previously matched
    [a-z]+ # match one or more lowercase letters
    /x

 "123abc"[r] #=> "abc"
```